# How to report a bootstrap for a journal? What all should we report?

Tags: bootstrap, reporting

So, the APA has a format for reporting an ANOVA along the lines of (F(df1,df2) = NN.NN, p<=0.05).

I am wondering if I end up bootstrapping my ANOVA, do I just need to mention that a boostrap has been done for say 10k times, or do I need to report anything else?

EDIT: I am looking at an Output from SPSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you should mention the number of bootstrap replicates you have used and it is the only parameter you should report.